# Enable / disable Submit button if the count in s:iterator value is great than 0

Tags: list, jsp, struts2, ognl

I have the following code in my JSP , Im using Struts2

```
<s:iterator value="incentiveList" status="stat">
    <tr>
        <td><s:checkbox name="checkboxes[%{#stat.index}]" theme="simple" /></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><s:property value="marketingAmount" /> <s:hidden value="%{incentiveList.marketingAmount}" /></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><s:property value="marketingIncentive" /></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><s:property value="advertizingIncentive" /></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><s:property value="channelPlacementIncentive" /></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</s:iterator>
</table>
</br>
</br>
<s:if test="#status.index gt 0">
<s:submit id="submitButton" name="submit" value="Submit Incentives" onclick='return closeWindow()'/>
</s:if>
<s:else>
<s:submit id="submitButton" name="submit" value="Submit Incentives" onclick='return closeWindow()' disabled="true"/>
</s:else>
```

Now I want to enable submitButton if incentiveList above has any value i.e count gt 0 and to achieve this I used below code

```
<s:if test="#status.index gt 0">
            <s:submit id="submitButton" name="submit" value="Submit Incentives" onclick='return closeWindow()'/>
            </s:if>
            <s:else>
            <s:submit id="submitButton" name="submit" value="Submit Incentives" onclick='return closeWindow()' disabled="true"/>
</s:else>
```

**but it is not working , please correct if anything is missed out**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `incentiveList` has no values, you won't get anything, not only the buttons. You will endd up with invalid `<table></table>` code, then the `<s:if>` should be put around the iterator too:

```
<s:if test="incentiveList.size()>0">
    <!-- iterator here -->

    <!-- buttons here -->
</s:if>
```

P.S: IteratorStatus is iterator-scoped (and iteration-scoped), it won't exist outside the Iterator, and it would be useless since it carries informations about the currently iterated element

Comment: Thanks Andrea

What do you think of 
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<c:if test="${fn:length(incentiveList) gt 0}">
    <s:submit id="submitButton" name="submit" value="Submit Incentives" onclick='return closeWindow()' disabled="true"/>
   </c:if>

Comment: What should I think... :) it's another good way, I prefer Struts tags and OGNL and I've used them in my answer because you've used them in your question :) BTW remember to put the IF (whatever kind you'll choice to use) around the whole table, or to create a <tr> with the <th> elements outside the iterator, or you will end up with invalid HTML